# Scikit-learn's SAMME AdaBoost error fraction implementation

Tags: scikit-learn, boosting, adaboost

I am taking a look at scikit-learn's [discrete SAMME implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1.2.2/sklearn/ensemble/_weight_boosting.py#L633) and came across the following logic for computing the weighted error fraction.

```py
# Instances incorrectly classified
incorrect = y_predict != y

# Error fraction
estimator_error = np.mean(np.average(incorrect, weights=sample_weight, axis=0))
```

**My question:** Why the use of `np.mean(...)` and `np.average(...)`?

---

At least in the following example, the output would be unchanged if the outer `np.mean(...)` call were removed.

```py
incorrect = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
weights = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2])

average = np.average(incorrect, axis=0, weights=weights)
mean_average = np.mean(average)

print("average:       ", average)
print("mean(average): ", mean_average)
```

Output:

```
average:        0.4
mean(average):  0.4
```

Since the documentation for the `AdaBoostClassifer` states that `y` [should be an array like](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.fit), I don't think I am missing anything about the dimensionality. But then, what am I missing?